# MVC 4 / IIS 7.5 - Prompting for windows authentication credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a MVC4 application which is using Windows Authentication. Both my computer (developing) and the host server are running IIS 7.5 and are on the same domain. The application has it's own app pool which is using NetworkService identity. The application only has Windows Authentication enabled.

During development I didn't have any security, I was just showing the user's name. This worked fine on my local IIS, and on the server's IIS, from multiple computers with multiple users.

As soon as I add an AuthorizeAttribute I start getting prompted for credentials, in both Chrome and IE. Using Fiddler I can see that an NTLM authentication header is being sent, but apparently ignored. If I go ahead and enter my credentials, I'm allowed access.

This is happening both locally and on the server, when trying to view the site remotely and locally (remote desktop). Removing the AuthorizeAttribute again instantly means I don't get the prompt.

I've done a lot of searching and tried a few long shots with no success. What else should I try?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: Different groups of people in our organisation should only have access to certain controllers/actions. We're trying to use groups to achieve this. The groups are working fine if you type in your credentials, but we don't want the prompt. In my previous experience I've never got this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely with your browser configuration. Browsers don't allow all sites to use NTLM by default. IE only allows sites in the Intranet zone to authenticate using NTLM and [it seems](https://superuser.com/questions/61063/can-i-get-chrome-to-work-with-sites-that-use-windows-integrated-security) Chrome has replicated that behaviour by now.

So, to get your site working go to the Internet Options in Internet Explorer and add your domain to the Intranet sites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris, I've tried adding it to every list in the security tab on IE after reading elsewhere that it could be a browser issue. I just tried again with no luck. Checked Chrome and Firefox after making the changes too.

Comment: @Zac Firefox has a different mechanism for determining whether to use NTLM authentication, see http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/ So far, this has always worked for me. Just to make sure: Are you logged into your domain account on the machine you are running the browser on (as opposed to, say, local admin account)? And is this account part of the same domain the server uses for authentication?

Comment: I tried that link and it didn't work. But practically no one uses Firefox here; It's mostly Chrome. So that's my main concern.

Comment: As I mentioned, in Fiddler I can see that Chrome is indeed sending some windows authentication headers. I still get prompted.

It's definitely on the same domain, and when I manually enter my details it works, which is even weirder. It's the same domain credentials I used to log into the computer.

Comment: @Zac Sorry, I'm out of ideas. This setup has always worked for me. Maybe try re-checking your server config.

Comment: Hi Chris, it seems the problem got solved by a colleague. I posted the solution and instructions as an answer, but I'll mark yours as the correct answer since it's basically what you said :) I'm not sure what I did 2 years ago, though. Oh well.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One of my colleagues managed to solve this problem only recently. It seems it was caused by the fact we have a local DNS suffix. The suffix is similar to `abc.local`, so all machines here are accessed like `http://hostname.abc.local`.

This was a problem because Internet Explorer (from which Chrome is taking its settings) did not think the website was part of the `Local Intranet` zone, and therefore didn't trust it enough.

Following the insutrctions in this diagram fixed the problem:

[image]

Note that whether `Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone` should be ticked may be different for you.